# onActivityResult() never called when Home is used instead of Back

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've got an app that launches another activity via startActivityForResult.  Everything works great if the user exits the invoked Activity via back button, however if the user presses Home instead, the invoked Activity exits and onActivityResult never gets called.

Is this expected behavior or should this work?

Comment: please put your code otherwise you will give negative score.

Comment: I revised my question slightly;  i really just need to know whether or not this is "expected" behavior for the moment, not my code debugged.

Comment: The problem is that when one clicks the home button the invoked activity and all the activities on the activity stack "gets minimized" (so to speak). Unless and until the invoked Activity finishes or calls setResult(..), onActivityResult will not be called.

Comment: @Umesh That sounds about right.  The weird part is that the invoked Activity is actually getting destroyed, or at least it is removed from the list of running processes on the device.  I'm confounded as to how it can be ended without the Activity having its normal lifecycle methods called.  Does Android handle this as a special case somehow?

Comment: Read [developer.android.com/guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Comment: @AVD - I've read through that several times.  Is there a specific section you are citing?

Comment: @Umesh - It is not an Activity defined within my application, however it is instantiated within my application, which was part of my confusion; I expected to see it in the task manager as  it's own line item, when in reality it will only show my app since it is a part of that process.  Bottom line: the Activity was not being ended at all and was being put in the background just as you said.  I was getting confused by the fact that I couldnt seem to find it in the task manager and assumed that meant it was being killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Difference Between Pressing Home Button and Back Button.

By default, pressing the Back button finishes (destroys) the current activity and displays the previous activity to the user.

By Default , pressing the Home Button activity is stopped and moved to the background rather than being destroyed

[More in Details](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html) - **Read Navigating Away from an Activity with Back and Home buttons**

Comment: Thanks - that doc lead me to the root cause of my confusion; I was calling an activity that is external to my app and was expecting it to be listed as its own process, when in fact it's actually grouped with my application process.